# vscode debug console autocomplete

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm using VS Code for javascript debug (Chrome).  (In some ways more convenient than Chrome Developer Tools, and can use both together ... but that is not the issue).

Autocomplete works sensibly for code in the code edit area.  However, in the debug console command line it makes some absurd context dependent choices,  e.g replacing 'false' with 'setRotationFromAxisAngle', or 'FontFaceSetLoadEvent'.  This can be fixed for example by adding a blank, but inconvenient.  Is there any way to make sure in knows true and false are javascript keywords and to accept them (and even to suggest them)